# Cant connect to db using docker

Tags: .net, docker, api

I have two images - database and api.

When i run a DB image and an api project (not an image). Everything is working fine, the data is coming.

But when i try to run two images i have this -

`network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)`

db code for container assembly - `docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=super_duper_password' -e 'MSSQL_PID=Express' -p 1433:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019`

Dockerfile webapi -

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["DockerSample.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "DockerSample.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "DockerSample.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "DockerSample.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerSample.dll"]
```

Connection string to DB in ConfigureServices -

```
services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(opt =>
                opt.UseSqlServer("Data Source=localhost,1433;Initial Catalog=TestDockerDb;User ID=sa;Password=Pa55sw0rd2022"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try 127.0.0.1? (Instead of localhost)